# How do I resolve menu activating problem in vuetify?

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I want to make the menu with subgroup using vuetify.
When a sub-menu is clicked, the sub-menu of the clicked menu is not activated, but the sub-menu of the final menu is always activated.

It seems like an activator problem caused by v-for. How can I solve it?

Header.vue

```
<v-list>
    <template v-for="menu in menus">        
        <template v-if="menu.sub">
            <v-list-group
                :value="menu.title"                           
                >
                <template v-slot:activator="{props}">
                    <v-list-item                                        
                        :prepend-icon="menu.icon"
                        :title="menu.title"
                        :value="menu.title"
                        v-bind="props"                                        
                        >                                        
                    </v-list-item>
                </template>
                <v-list-item v-for="submenu in menu.sub"
                    :title="submenu.title"
                    :value="submenu.title"
                    :to="submenu.to"
                    >
                </v-list-item>
            </v-list-group>
        </template>

        <template v-else>
            <v-list-item 
                :title="menu.title"
                :prepend-icon="menu.icon"
                :value="menu.title"
                :to="menu.to"
            ></v-list-item>
        </template>

    </template>
</v-list>

const menus = [
    {
        title: 'Dashboard',
        icon: 'mdi-home',        
        to: '/Dashboard',
    },
    {
        title: 'Member Info',
        icon: 'mdi-account-circle',        
        to: '/Member',
        sub: [
            { 
                title: 'List1',
                icon:  'settings',
                to: '/Member',
            },
            { 
                title: 'List2',
                icon:  'settings',
                to: '/about',
            },

        ]
    },
    {   
        title: 'Board' ,
        icon: 'mdi-inbox-arrow-down',
        to: '/about',
        sub: [
            { 
                title: 'sub1',
                icon:  'settings',
                to: '/Member',
            },
            { 
                title: 'sub2',
                icon:  'settings',
                to: '/about',
            },
        ]
    },
    {   
        title: 'Cash',
        icon: 'mdi-widgets',
        to: '/notfound',
        sub: [
            { 
                title: 'sub3',
                icon:  'settings',
                to: '/Member',
            },
            { 
                title: 'sub4',
                icon:  'settings',
                to: '/about',
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        title: 'Fin',
        icon: 'mdi-home',        
        to: '/Dashboard',
    },
]
```

App.vue code

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app id="inspire">
    <Header/>
    <RouterView/>
    <Footer/>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import Header from '@pages/Header.vue';
import Footer from '@pages/Footer.vue';
</script>
```

Router > index.ts

```
import {createRouter, createWebHashHistory, RouteRecordRaw} from 'vue-router';

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Dashboard',
        component: () => import('@pages/Dashboard.vue'),
    },

    {
        path: '/member',
        name: "Member",
        component: () => import('@pages/Member.vue'),
    },

    {
        path: '/about',
        name: "About",
        component: () => import('@pages/about.vue'),
    },

    {
        path: "/notFound",
        name: "notFound",
        component: () => import('@pages/notfound.vue'),
    },

    {
        path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*",
        redirect: "/notFound"
    }
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHashHistory(),
    routes,
})

export default router;
```

I want the activator to work properly

Comment: It works when I put your code into a playground. When I click the submenu, it takes the value from the submenu and marks the correct entry as active. My guess is that the problem comes from your routes. Can you add route declaration and content of `menus` to the question?

Comment: @MoritzRingler I added the other code with router. Can U check one more?

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is that the submenu entries all go to the same pages (`/Member` and `/about`). Since you are using `:to`, the active element is not set from where you clicked, but from the URL. If you set different routes in the submenus, does it work?

Comment: Problem solved. The cause was that the menus created temporarily as a test were linking to the same page, so I need to check more details about the router concept. Thank you so much!